# Why is ":" giving me an invalid syntax in python?

Tags: if-statement

I've been trying to make this code worked but is giving me a confusing error (been trying to figure out during the weekend)

```
numberone = ("Failed")
user = int(input("Enter any number: ")
if user > 15:
    print(numberone)
    
    else:
        print("well guessed")

File "<string>", line 3
    if user > 15:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Look at the line *before* the reported error.

Comment: I think you're missing `)` at here `user = int(input("Enter any number: ")`

Comment: Yeah that was the issue. thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't close the bracket in the previous line.
You have:

```
user = int(input("Enter any number: ")
```

And should be:

```
user = int(input("Enter any number: "))
```

Also, there is a problem with the `else` statement. It should be right under the `if` (in python it is important)

In general, this should work:

```
numberone = ("Failed")
user = int(input("Enter any number: "))
if user > 15:
    print(numberone)
else:
    print("well guessed")
```